# How to increase the number of minor ticks in a plot?

Tags: plotting, ticks

I want to increase the number of minor ticks in a plot, but I don't want to label them. I searched through this site and also *Mathematica* documentation, but I didn't find any solution yet. Could anyone please tell me how to do this.

For an example:

```
Plot[2*Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {True, True, False, False}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

I want to get 10 minor tick marks in between 0 and 1 and so on (in between major tick marks on both axis).

[image: Here is the output plot]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's another approach, very similar to swish's. The difference being that it should work on all sorts of plot ranges.

The idea is to define a `ticks` function with `min_` and `max_` (idea from `Ticks` in documentation):

```
ticks[min_, max_] := 
  Table[If[FractionalPart[i] == 0., {i, i, .06, Red}, {i, "", .02,Blue}], 
  {i, Floor[min], Ceiling[max], 0.1}]
```

Then the graph:

```
Plot[2*Sin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {ticks, ticks, False, False}, Axes -> True]
```

and we get:

[image]

we note that we could use any condition within the `Table` in `ticks` (e.g. use `Switch` or `Which` to get mid-ticks, etc.

Also, here is a version that let's the user specify ranges of noteworthy ticks directly:

```
r1 = Range[-3, 3, 0.2];

r2 = Range[-3, 3, 0.1];

tickfreq = 0.05;

ticks[min_, max_] := 
 Table[With[{val = Round[Abs@FractionalPart[i], 0.01]}, 
   Which[Chop[Min[Abs[r1 - val]]] == 0, {i, i, .06, Red}, 
    Chop[Min[Abs[r2 - val]]] == 0, {i, "", .04, Green}, 
    1 < 2, {i, "", .02, Blue}]], {i, Floor[min], Ceiling[max], 
   tickfreq}]
```

where `tickfreq` specifies the frequency of the blue (base-) ticks, `r1` the red ticks (with labels), `r2` the green additional ticks. Using then the `PlotRange` you specify in the comments, we get:

```
Plot[2*Sin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {ticks, ticks, False, False}, Axes -> True, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 3.5}, {-0.25, 0.3}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, one could also use different `ticks` version for the axes, but I am sure you get the idea. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually want to increase the height of minor ticks at middle of each major tick marks too.(minor ticks at -2.5,-1.5,-0.5,0.5,..)Could you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: If my plot range is `PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 3.5}, {-0.25, 0.3}}`Can I still use FractionalPart[i]? I just want to show integers in x axis, but I want to get y axis as -0.25,-0.15,-0.05,0.05,0.15,0.25. I tried to get this, but I still couldn't get it. Could you please tell me how to get it?

Comment: I tried with this, `ticks[min_, max_] := 
 Table[Switch[Abs@FractionalPart[i*10], 0.5, {i, i, .06, Red}, 
   0., {i, i, .04, Green}, _, {i, "", .02, Blue}], {i, Floor[min], 
   Ceiling[max], 0.01}]

Plot[2*Sin[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, ticks, False, False}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 3.5}, {-0.25, 0.3}}, Axes -> True]` But, I still couldn't get the expected output.

Comment: I am sorry for all the edits, the numerical values caused me some problems. I am using `Chop` now in a version that let's you specify `r1` (red ticks, labeled) and `r2` (green ticks), rest is blue ticks. I hope you are able to finally do your chart - good luck, I have to run!

Comment: Thanks a lot Pinguin for paying attention on my problem. As I told my plot range is `PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 3.5}, {-0.25, 0.3}}` When I run the edited code, still I couldn't get the expected out come. I tried several times. Actually, I spend all the day for this, but still I couldn't successful.

Comment: @THM: I updated again, I hope you see better what's going on. I explicitly stated `r1, r2, tickfreq` (which you should adjust to get the desired results). If it still doesn't work, we maybe should meet on chat to fix things.

Comment: I would like to come to a chat.

Comment: all settled in chat :)

Comment: Can I chat with you to discuss another version of this problem?

Comment: sure, you set up a chat room? (I still don't know how to do that)

Comment: It seems to be our times are different.I will describe my problem here. In this case, x- axis goes from 5 to 250. I want to have labels on 50,100,150,200,250 and lengths of the ticks should be same as on the previous problem. I tried with editing the previous code, but I still couldn't get it. Really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: ok sure: you could start with `r1 = Range[0, 250, 50];r2 = Range[25, 250, 50];tickfreq = 5;`; next, for the `ticks`, we need to remove the `FractionalPart` etc, so get: `ticks[min_, max_] := 
 Table[With[{val = i}, 
   Which[Chop[Min[Abs[r1 - val]]] == 0, {i, i, .06, Red}, 
    Chop[Min[Abs[r2 - val]]] == 0, {i, "", .04, Green}, 
    1 < 2, {i, "", .02, Blue}]], {i, Floor[min], Ceiling[max], 
   tickfreq}];`, finally plot: `Plot[x, {x, 5, 250}, Frame -> True,FrameTicks -> {ticks, ticks, False, False}, Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{5, 250}, {5, 250}}]`. Does that yield what you wanted?

Comment: Exactly.That's what I tried.Thank you so much. You are very helpful person.

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

You can always manually specify the ticks with its labels, size and style

```
ticks = ({#, "", {.01, .005}, Red} & /@ Range[0.1, .9, .1])~Join~Range[0, 10, 1]
Plot[2*Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {ticks, True, False, False}, Axes -> True, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can I increase the height of ticks at 0.5,1,1.5,2,...and so on?

Comment: `FindDivisions[]` would be a very handy function here...

Comment: @swish Thanks. I actually want sub ticks for all range and to increase the height of tick marks which are located at 0,0.5,1,1.5 and 2. (I don't want to increase the height of all ticks) How to edit the above code for that purpose?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the comment. But, I don't know how to use it for my problem.

Comment: @TMH You can make it yourself, just specify the list of ticks you want `{tick1, tick2, ...}` with `tickN` of format `{position, label, {positive_size, negative_size}, style}`.

Comment: @swish Could you please tell me how to join tickN which is a list of ticks inside the plot command?

Comment: @TMH Just try to analyse the code in the answer, when you will understand how it works you will answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way that uses [`FindDivisions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDivisions.html) and the default ticks (via the undocumented ticks function `` Charting`ScaledTicks ``, which you can find [all over this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=ScaledTicks)):

```
ClearAll[myTicks, major, minor]; 
myTicks[div_, h_Symbol: Charting`ScaledTicks, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[Charting`ScaledTicks]] :=
 With[{styles = DeleteDuplicatesBy[#[[3]] &]@
      Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, opts][0., 1.]},
   major[Charting`ScaledFrameTicks] := 
    Evaluate@ReplacePart[First[styles], {1 -> #, 2 -> ""}] &;
   major[Charting`ScaledTicks] := 
    Evaluate@ReplacePart[First[styles], {1 -> #, 2 -> #}] &;
   minor = Evaluate@ReplacePart[Last[styles], {1 -> #}] &;
   Flatten[
    MapThread[
     #1 /@ Flatten[#2] &,
     {{major[h], minor}, FindDivisions[{##}, div]}
     ],
    1]] &;
```

One can inspect `` Options[Charting`ScaledTicks] ``, but `"TicksLength"` is the only one I can find a use for in this context.  It can only be used to set the "positive" length (into the plot).  The "negative" length is hard-coded to `0.`.

Example:

```
Plot[2*Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {
   {myTicks[{5, 11}, "TicksLength" -> {0.03, 0.015}], 
    myTicks[{5, 11}, Charting`ScaledFrameTicks, "TicksLength" -> {0.03, 0.015}]},
   {myTicks[{11, 11}], 
    myTicks[{11, 11}, Charting`ScaledFrameTicks]}},
 Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Folks who like to hijack the system may be amused by this:

```
ClearAll[myTicks];
myTicks[div_, h_: Charting`ScaledTicks] := 
  Internal`InheritedBlock[{Visualization`Divisions},
    Unprotect[Visualization`Divisions];
    Visualization`Divisions[{##}, {6, 6}, 10, ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, Identity}] := 
     FindDivisions[{##}, div];
    Protect[Visualization`Divisions];
    h[{Identity, Identity}][##]
    ] &;
```

It works similar to the above, but without the options. It basically allows you to set the tick divisions from the hard-coded default `{6, 6}` to whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

We can (1) use the optional third argument of `` Charting`ScaledTicks[..] `` to specify the number of major and minor ticks (2) use the same ticks spec for left and right (and bottom and top) frames, (3) hide the labels in top and right frames using `FontOpacity -> 0` as the `FrameStyle`:

```
Plot[2*Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, FontOpacity -> 0}, {Automatic, FontOpacity -> 0}}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{#, #} & @ (Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
      "TicksLength" -> {0.03, 0.015}][##, {5,  11}] &), 
    {#, #} & @ (Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
      "TicksLength" -> {0.03, 0.015}][##, {11, 11}] &)}, 
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]