# Graphics with grid lines

Tags: graphics, ticks

With the following example code

```
Graphics[
  {
    Line[{{0, 0}, {6, 6}}]
  }, ImageSize -> {500, 500}, Frame -> True
]
```

I get:

[image]

How can I produce grid lines vertically and horizontally each 0.5 steps.
The small tick marks should be 0.5 apart and the large 1.

How can that be done in the Graphics environment?

Comment: `Graphics` takes the option `GridLines`.

Comment: Do you want to create `GridLines` or `Ticks`? Either way, documentation answers your question, right?

Comment: Look into the `Graphics` options `GridLines` and `Ticks`

Comment: @Kuba: both, small ticks should be each 0.5 steps, large ticks each 1 step, and the grid lines should be at both axes each 0.5 steps.

Comment: But what from documentation is not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myRange = Range[0, 6, 0.5]
```

> {0., 0.5, 1., 1.5, 2., 2.5, 3., 3.5, 4., 4.5, 5., 5.5, 6.}

```
Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {6, 6}}]}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {myRange, myRange}]
```

[image]

And directly from the documentation:

```
grids[min_, max_] := 
Join[Range[Ceiling[min], Floor[max]], 
Table[{j + .5, Dashed}, {j, Round[min], Round[max - 1], 1}]]

Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {6, 6}}]}, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {grids, grids}]
```

[image]

Comment: how do you set the small ticks each 0.5 steps?

Comment: @mrz, see [How to increase the number of minor ticks in a plot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24371/how-to-increase-the-number-of-minor-ticks-in-a-plot) all else is automatic.